# HTTP ERROR 503 Service unavailable in Jetty server

Tags: java, netbeans, jetty

Everytime I try to run a simple jetty server on netbeans i am facing this error, please note previously it was working fine, now all of a sudden it is giving me this error, has there been any updates? Am i missing something. please note this is web.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
<Set name="contextPath">/Fc_jetty</Set>
</Configure>
```

Answer (score 3):

Solved by myself after a lot of trial and error,finally got the cause that was the netbeans plugin compatible issue with the jetty server on downgrading the server to 9.2 the problem is gone, if someone is facing similar kind of issue please try this it will be solved